# Column 'Payment.Amount' is invalid in the select list

Tags: sql-server

```
select 
    Resident.FirstName, tab.PaymentDate, tab.Amount 
from 
    Resident 
cross apply (
     select top 1 
         Amount, PaymentDate 
     from Payment 
     where Resident.Id = Payment.ResidentId 
     group by payment.ResidentId
) tab
```

Error which I am getting is

> Column 'Payment.Amount' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Comment: Why do you have a `group by` in that subquery anyways? There's no **aggregate function** like `SUM`, `COUNT`, `MIN`, `MAX` anywhere at all .....

Comment: And if you do need to do that, the error tells you the fix, either group-by or aggregate the column in question.

Comment: And why use cross apply when you're joining?

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
    Resident.FirstName, tab.PaymentDate, tab.Amount 
from 
    Resident 
cross apply (
     select top 1 ,
         Amount, PaymentDate 
     from Payment 
     where Resident.Id = Payment.ResidentId 
     group by payment.ResidentId
) tab
```

Comment: please provide explanation about answer. Not just sql statement.

Comment: comma was missed, which I added. I hope this works. For correcting the SQL actual data will be needed. I tried correcting the syntax for now.

Comment: no. it is not the error. adding comma will throw error message. Whatver be it, please add explanation

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to apply GROUP BY and have not defined aggregate for other columns in the SELECT list. When you apply GROUP BY, only GROUP BY columns & aggregate functions can come in the SELECT list.

I think you are trying to get minimum amount, minimum payment date from CROSS APPLY. You can calculate as given below:

```sql
select 
    Resident.FirstName, tab.PaymentDate, tab.Amount 
from 
    Resident 
cross apply (
     select  min(Amount) as Amount, min(PaymentDate) as PaymentDate
     from Payment 
     where Resident.Id = Payment.ResidentId 
     group by payment.ResidentId
) tab
```